# Are the "invaded" levels optional in Rayman Legends?

Tags: rayman-legends

I tried the demo of Rayman Legends, and it features one "invaded" level.

Given the higher difficulty (and resulting frustration), I was wondering if such levels are optional or not in the main game.

If they are here only to unlock skins and stuff, it won't matter much to me. If I have to finish such levels to unlock more of the regular ones, it is more problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about that, these levels are just optional

Comment: They are optional, but to be honest if you find them too hard you're going to hit a brick wall of difficulty about 3/4 of the way through the game.

Answer (score 1):

They are optional. I have gotten 100% in the game except for the last character.
Believe me, they're a whole lot easier after you beat the game. (Relating to your gained skill not level design.)